# SmartGWT: Applying style from CSS

Tags: css, smartgwt

I have a IButton instance and I want to change its name and color after click.

```
       button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {  
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {  
                if(button.getTitle().equals("Enabled")) {
                    button.setTitle("Disabled");
                    button.setTitleStyle("disabledButton");
                }
                else {
                    button.setTitle("Enabled");
                    button.setTitleStyle("enabledButton");
                }                   
            }
       });
```

As we do in general GWT project, 
I have added following to the default .css file:

```
.enabledButton {
  color:green;
}

.disabledButton {
  color:red;
}
```

But when I run the application, it is not showing either red or green color.

Is there any other way in SmartGWT to apply CSS styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IButton is a StatefulCanvas, which means it handles states. This is done by adding suffixes after the base style name. For example if you set the titleStyle to "enableButton" and you move your mouse over the button, it will look for the css class: enableButtonOver. If the button is also focused, it will look for enableButtonFocusedOver etc (there are a couple of suffix combinations). Your example works if you click outside from the browser, so it will lost the focus and simply will use the enableButton css class. You can disable each state by for example setShowFocused(false). See the [api](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/StatefulCanvas.html).